# What's the process of Mac OSX's calendar notification popup called, and can I sudo kill it?

Tags: macos, mac, notifications

I hate those notifications you cannot really decline or dismiss. Last time the notification center graced me with a safari advertisement which you either comply to by trying 'the new and oh so efficient piece of crap' or tell the popup to bother you 'later'.
I wanted to sudo kill the popup bar, but couldn't find the process related to it. Can somebody help me find it? Is it a subprocess of the notification center?
From its looks it must be the same origin as calendar notification popups. So, which process spawns them?

EDIT: Pictures.

[image: The safari popup]

another:

[image: A calendar notification]

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of the notification or tell us what the exact content was? I never saw something like that on OS X. If it was from a specific application (maybe the App Store?) you can most likely disable the notifications in the preferences of the application which emitted the notification. Taking a look at System Preferences -> Notifications could help too.

Comment: I had a talk about the safari popup with apple support. I think it's a complete disgrace that apple bothers me with in such an intrusive way to try their products. It always popped up when starting chrome. Now I wanted to get rid of it without having to comply by hitting 'Later' on the safari popup. I wanted to kill it (with fire), but couldn't find the process.

Comment: I could find the exact same question on AskDifferent (within 2 seconds of google) [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153379/disable-try-the-new-safari-popup). I think this solves your problem.

Comment: No, it does not. It may seem to you, that the topics are alike, but in fact, I was asking how I could kill the process of the graphical notification popup itself, and not how I can configure my system, so they do not reappear.

Comment: I tried another approach at solving your problem because sudo killing system processes is in my opinion not the best way to accomplish what you are trying. Killing system processes has usually side effects on the whole system performance and that's the reason why you can't easily kill notifyd (I think that's the process your searching for, but I'm not 100% certain). If you kill it (or Notification Center) it respawns instantly. Sorry that I bothered you with my approach.

Comment: Hmm, I tried ending notifyd, but interestingly the popup persisted. Yeah, the process then respawns right away. You are right though, killing a system process usually causes trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Safari pop-up, there's this answer on apple.stackexchange.com:

[How to disable the "Try the new Safari" popup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153379/disable-try-the-new-safari-popup)

For other Notifications that force you to interact, you can change them for each application into "Banner" or "None" type within System Preferences > Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Citing [the top answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153379/disable-try-the-new-safari-popup) on AskDifferent:

> You can get rid of it without giving in to Apple‘s desire for you to
>   “Try Now”. Even if you click the button, they will ask you to change
>   your default and may still ask again at a later time. I have explained
>   it in much [greater details on my
>   blog](https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/osx-try-safari-promotion.html) but
>   the gist of it are these three commands:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.coreservices.uiagent CSUIHasSafariBeenLaunched -bool YES
> defaults write com.apple.coreservices.uiagent CSUIRecommendSafariNextNotificationDate -date 2050-01-01T00:00:00Z
> defaults write com.apple.coreservices.uiagent CSUILastOSVersionWhereSafariRecommendationWasMade -float 10.99
> ```
>
> You must log out and in again for the change to apply. You should
>   actually do it immediately to prevent the system from reverting the
>   changes.
>
> I also cover how to [stop Safari from prompting you to become the
>   default](https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/osx-try-safari-promotion.html#section-safari-exit-prompt)
>   every few days.
>   ([epimorphic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/23454) touched on
>   this briefly.) Interesting if you need to use Safari on occasions for
>   site-compatibility, testing, or whatever reason. (Oddly enough, I have
>   not heard any automated browsing test suite authors complaining about
>   this yet.)